# How to prevent tramp locations from interfering in history?

Tags: dired, tramp

I have an issue where if I try to perform some random Emacs operations such as `org-capture`, or renaming a file to a different (local) directory in `dired`, Emacs attempts to contact a different machine using tramp, presumably for some sort of auto-completion or history reasoning. This causes a lot of hanging and waiting, because the machine tramp is trying to connect to is not available.

How can I prevent Emacs from looking up tramp files/locations when I perform other rudimentary operations? How can I determine where and how Emacs is getting the idea that it needs to look inside a remote file/location for operations like `org-capture` and `dired-do-rename`?

Comment: Assuming that there is a short delay before Emacs starts to contact a remote machine when you try to rename a file in Dired, try pressing `C-f` right after you hit `R`. Does that help?

Comment: The behaviour you're describing is not one I've ever experienced. Could you provide a minimal example?

Comment: I have experienced this behaviour before but with using helm as the completing read. I don't experience this with ido for example.

Comment: This question describes behavior that cannot be reproduced and is thus unlikely to help future visitors. If you can reproduce it, please edit the question to describe how.

Comment: If you have recentf <http://www.emacswiki.org/RecentFiles> enabled it may try to connect to remote machines.

I've got the following in my init.el file.

`(setq recentf-exclude '("~$" "/tmp/" "/ssh:" "/sudo:"))`

I set this up several years ago. Having remote files in the recent file list was causing me some problems but I don't remember the details.

You may have to remove all remote files from the recent file list manually. Its location is defined by the variable `recentf-save-file`.

Comment: Try enabling `debug-on-quit` by doing `M-x`toggle-debug-on-quit`RET` and then press `C-g` when emacs hangs. It would print a stacktrace, it might help debugging the problem

Comment: instrument the function `dired-do-rename` by using `M-x edebug-defun` and go step by step by pressing `n`. you will get the culprit who added tramp hook....

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that some code kicks in, due to a hook or advise, which should be using `remote-file-p` instead of `tramp-tramp-file-p`. Read the documentation of both and then grep the installed packages for the latter symbol, replacing it were appropriate. If that fixes the issue, start opening pull requests.